# How to properly use the Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: probability

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$If I put $X_i$ to be the result of the $i$-th dice roll out of 420, and $S$ to be the sum of results of the 420 dice rolls, then I have an expected value of $420\cdot 3.5$ and a variance of $1225$. Now how do I compute $P(S\ge 1400)$? I know I have to go look for $P\left({S-E(S)\over \sqrt{\Var(S)}}\ge{1400-E(S)\over \sqrt{\Var(S)}}\right)$, but everywhere I look, people just write the answer, and I don't know what they actually do when skipping to the answer. The integral in the theorem is not computable. So how is it calculated? I am so frustrated. I could really use your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\vphantom{\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\int}}\dfrac{1400-\operatorname{E}(S)}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(S)}}$ in this case is $\dfrac{1400-1470}{35}=-2$.  The random variable to the left of that has a standard normal distribution, and "standard" means having expected value $0$ and standard deviation $1$.  Thus you're looking for $\Pr(Z\ge-2)$.  The value of something like $\Pr(Z\ge-2)$ is almost always found either by looking it up in a table or by relying on software.  And if you want to know the algorithms used for creating the table or in the software, probably you should rephrase the question.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be $P(Z \geq -2)$?  The OP wants $P(S \geq 1400)$.

Comment: Sorry --- typo. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What I want to know is in what way it is to be computed. I go through my notes and the internet and I didn't quite understand.

Comment: If I use a table, doesn't it mean it has nothing to do with the theorem?

Comment: So you're wondering how the numbers in table are computed?  If so, it would probably be best to phrase the question differently.  You could say something like "How are the values of the cumulative distribution function for the normal distribution computed?" ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Ahh, as @MichaelHardy points out, that should be rephrased.  As it stands, your question looks like it's asking about the practical aspects of determining the tails of the normal distribution, which as he indicates is by way of either looking it up in a table, or relying on software.  The values in the tables are computed by (numerically) integrating the standard normal distribution from $z$ to $\infty$: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{x=z}^\infty e^{x^2/2} \, dx$.

Comment: @Meitar : The central limit theorem is certainly used to solve the problem involving dice by reducing it to finding $\Pr(Z\ge-2)$.  But as far as I know, the theorem is not used in doing the numerical computations by which the table is created.  I've never properly learned those methods, I've only glimpsed them.

Comment: Suppose I am not to use any written table or software, what can I do in order to find such a probability?

Comment: I guess it is not what I am expected....

Comment: @Meitar : Try posting a separate question that omits the part about throwing dice and the central limit theorm, and just ask how numerical computation of values of the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution are calculated.